# How to clone a specific attribute of an model instance in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello  I have a model named Client which has nested models called Receiver and Receipt.Basically a client donate money to a receiver or many receivers, and that gift appear in a receipt.

**model/client.rb**

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :receivers
  has_many :receipts

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :receivers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :receipts
end
```

**views/client/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @client do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :input %>
  <%= f.input :suscribtion_number %>
  <%= simple_fields_for :orders do |o| %>
    <%= o.input :name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Matter fact how can I dynamically transfer a client "input" to 
1- an oder's "amount"(attribute)
2- and to a receipt's "amount"(attribute)

Comment: You shouldn't shadow your form builder variable `f`. Give the second one another name, for example.

Comment: Sorry that's some bad omission by myself.I've fixed it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do `@receipt.amount = @client.amount`. However, the better way to  model this would be to have a `Donation` model with an `amount` attribute. Then, link clients and receivers to the donation.

The `donation` model would probably replace your `receipt` model. When you need to compute how much a client has donated, simply sum all the associated donation amounts.

By modeling the donation, you won't need to worry about keeping multiple copies of the same information (i.e. the donation amount) in sync. Having multiple copies of the same information is a bad idea, generally speaking.

Comment: Thanks David Sulc.I'll give the Donation model a shot.I don't even think about that aspect of things.