# How do I clone a Rails model attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, clone

How do I clone a single attribute in a Rails model? This didn't work:

```
irb(main):309:0> u.reload
=> #<User id: 1, username: "starrychloe", ...
irb(main):310:0> u2 = u.dup
=> #<User id: nil, username: "starrychloe", ...
irb(main):311:0> u2 = u.clone
=> #<User id: 1, username: "starrychloe", ...
irb(main):312:0> u2.username = u.username.clone
=> "starrychloe"
irb(main):313:0> u2.username = 'star'
=> "star"
irb(main):314:0> u.username ############ Changes original
=> "star"
```

Neither did this:

```
irb(main):320:0> u.reload
=> #<User id: 1, username: "starrychloe", ...
irb(main):321:0> u2 = u.clone
=> #<User id: 1, username: "starrychloe", ...
irb(main):322:0> u2[:username] = u[:username].clone
=> "starrychloe"
irb(main):323:0> u2.username = 'cow'
=> "cow"
irb(main):324:0> u.username ############ Changes original
=> "cow"
```

`#dup` doesn't copy the ID, and `#clone` on the attribute keeps the reference to the same string.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318080/how-to-clone-a-specific-attribute-of-an-model-instance-in-rails) will not solve my problem.

Comment: Using `dup` works and should not change your original instance attribute. I've tested this on Rails 4 and Ruby 2. `dup` does not copy the id as it initializes a new copy of the instance and therefore will not be the same object in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making copies of each of the fields I wanted to keep track of:

```
@oldUsername = @user.username.clone
```

`User.new` looked promising, but it treated the copy as a new object, when it was an existing model, and output invalid forms to edit the model in the views:

```
> app.controller.view_context.form_for u2 do end   # This is from Rails console
=> "<form accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" action=\"/users\" class=\"new_user\" id=\"new_user_1\" method=\"post\">
```

So it would attempt to PATCH to /users (from the view), which is invalid, when it should PATCH to /users/1/.

It's unbelievable that Rails won't clone objects correctly. In Java, you could use `u2.setProperty( u.getProperty().clone() )` and be sure to have a new object that won't interfere with the old one.

Answer (score 2):

```
u2 = User.new(u.attributes.merge(username: "cow"))
```

Also, take a look at this question. It has a lot of interesting info on similar subject:
[What is the easiest way to duplicate an activerecord record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-duplicate-an-activerecord-record)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to duplicate an instance or an attribute?

To duplicate an instance, use `u2 = u.dup` not `u2 = u.clone`.

Comment: Sorry - I may have misunderstood.  Are you trying to keep the id, too?

Comment: Yes I must keep the id so it doesn't insert a new record in the DB once saved.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna look into amoeba gem. https://github.com/rocksolidwebdesign/amoeba

Answer (score 0):

To make a copy of the instance with its attributes and de-reference you can do this:

```
u2 = u.class.new(u.attributes)
```

Comment: Peculiar, but it thinks it is a new object. Is there a way around that? `app.controller.view_context.form_for u2 do end`: `<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" id="new_user_1" method="post">...`.

Comment: ? I'm not in the view. That was from the Rails Console.

Comment: To edit. I do not want to display modified values outside of the edit form in case of validation errors, such as in the header or navigation panels.